# I wish to populate a particular div with a html page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two widgets in a row with 6columns each. I have written code for dynamically populating one widgets and i wish to add that widget in the home dashboard. I need it to load the content of that particular div on the go of the page load.I had written that div in seperate file to be used in multiple places. So i want to know how to load that div in my html. I have here mentioned the code here below of my 'main.html' which contains two 6 columns and i wanted to populate the first 6  column with other.html file which contains angular div.

```
    <!-- WIDGETS SPACE, PLACE SOME UIKITS HERE OR MAKE YOUR OWN KITS ;) -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- UPCOMMING NEW TESTS -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-actions-input">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">View all Test</a>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Upcoming Test New Tests</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="media">
                        <a class="pull-left kit-avatar kit-avatar-36" href="#">
                            <img class="media-object" src="images/dummy/uifaces1.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
                                    <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="approve" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="invoice" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-credit-card fa-fw"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="delete" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.btn-group -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.pull-right -->
                            <h5 class="media-heading"><a href="#">Purchase 4 items ($80)</a></h5>
                            <div class="text-muted">
                                <small><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> Rose Davies</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <small><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> 16 minutes</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.media-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.media -->
                    <hr>
                    <div class="media">
                        <a class="pull-left kit-avatar kit-avatar-36" href="#">
                            <img class="media-object" src="images/dummy/uifaces2.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
                                    <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="approve" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="invoice" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-credit-card fa-fw"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="delete" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.btn-group -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.pull-right -->
                            <h5 class="media-heading"><a href="#">Purchase an item - Wrapkit Admin Template</a></h5>
                            <div class="text-muted">
                                <small><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> Dilara Elmas</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <small><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> 20 minutes</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.media-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.media -->
                    <hr>
                    <div class="media">
                        <a class="pull-left kit-avatar kit-avatar-36" href="#">
                            <img class="media-object" src="images/dummy/uifaces3.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
                                    <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="approve" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="invoice" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-credit-card fa-fw"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="delete" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.btn-group -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.pull-right -->
                            <h5 class="media-heading"><a href="#">Payment for invoice #141213</a></h5>
                            <div class="text-muted">
                                <small><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> George Florianu</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <small><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> 42 minutes</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.media-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.media -->
                    <hr>
                    <div class="media">
                        <a class="pull-left kit-avatar kit-avatar-36" href="#">
                            <img class="media-object" src="images/dummy/uifaces4.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
                                    <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="approve" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="invoice" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-credit-card fa-fw"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="delete" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.btn-group -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.pull-right -->
                            <h5 class="media-heading"><a href="#">Purchase an item - Wrapkit Admin Template</a></h5>
                            <div class="text-muted">
                                <small><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> Gustavo Francisco</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <small><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> 1 hours</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.media-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.media -->
                    <hr>
                    <div class="media">
                        <a class="pull-left kit-avatar kit-avatar-36" href="#">
                            <img class="media-object" src="images/dummy/uifaces5.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
                                    <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="approve" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="invoice" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-credit-card fa-fw"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="delete" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.btn-group -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.pull-right -->
                            <h5 class="media-heading"><a href="#">Purchase an item - Wrapkit Admin Template</a></h5>
                            <div class="text-muted">
                                <small><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> Bastien Guichard</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <small><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> 1 hours</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.media-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.media -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel -->
            <!-- END OF RECENTS ORDER KITS -->

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- TOP RANK (users, items or others) KIT -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <h3 class="panel-title">Weekly list of Toppers
                                        <br>
                                        <small class="text-muted">Updated at 07:16 am</small>
                                           </h3>

                    <div class="media">
                        <a class="pull-left kit-avatar kit-avatar-36" href="#">
                            <img class="media-object" src="images/dummy/uifaces11.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h5 class="media-heading">Emma Greene</h5>
                            <div class="progress progress-md">
                                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="1500" style="width: 8.33%">
                                    <div class="progress-text">0 Right Answers</div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.progress-bar -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.progress -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.media-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.media -->
                    <div class="media">
                        <a class="pull-left kit-avatar kit-avatar-36" href="#">
                            <img class="media-object" src="images/dummy/uifaces12.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h5 class="media-heading">Júlia Márta</h5>
                            <div class="progress progress-md">
                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="1500" style="width: 74.8%">
                                    <div class="progress-text">1,122 sales</div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.progress-bar -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.progress -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.media-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.media -->
                    <div class="media">
                        <a class="pull-left kit-avatar kit-avatar-36" href="#">
                            <img class="media-object" src="images/dummy/uifaces13.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h5 class="media-heading">Tom Bonnet</h5>
                            <div class="progress progress-md">
                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="1500" style="width: 69.27%">
                                    <div class="progress-text">1,039 sales</div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.progress-bar -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.progress -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.media-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.media -->
                    <div class="media">
                        <a class="pull-left kit-avatar kit-avatar-36" href="#">
                            <img class="media-object" src="images/dummy/uifaces14.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h5 class="media-heading">Naia Gómez</h5>
                            <div class="progress progress-md">
                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="1500" style="width: 64.8%">
                                    <div class="progress-text">972 sales</div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.progress-bar -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.progress -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.media-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.media -->
                    <div class="media">
                        <a class="pull-left kit-avatar kit-avatar-36" href="#">
                            <img class="media-object" src="images/dummy/uifaces15.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h5 class="media-heading">Gary Lewis</h5>
                            <div class="progress progress-md">
                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="1500" style="width: 58.73%">
                                    <div class="progress-text">881 sales</div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.progress-bar -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.progress -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.media-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.media -->

                    <br>
                    <!--Just line-->

                </div>
                <!-- /.panel-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel -->
            <!-- /END TOP RANK KIT -->
        </div>







        <!-- /.cols -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

</div>
```

The other.html contains the below code.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-actions-input">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">View all Test</a>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Upcoming Test</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="media" ng-repeat="item in testList track by $index">
                        <a class="pull-left kit-avatar kit-avatar-36" href="#">
                            <img class="media-object" src="images/dummy/uifaces1.jpg" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
                                    <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Attend Test" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>Going To Attend Test</a>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.btn-group -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.pull-right -->
                            <h5 class="media-heading"><a href="#">{{item.title}}</a></h5>
                            <div class="text-muted">
                                <small><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>{{item.questionPoster}}</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <small><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> {{item.timePosted}}</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <!-- /.media-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.media -->


                    <!-- /.panel -->
                    <!-- END OF RECENTS ORDER KITS -->
                    {{variable}}
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: where is the angular code here?

Comment: <div class="media" ng-repeat="item in testList track by $index"> Iam loading up the array data to that divs.

Comment: ok, so then where is `item` used?

Comment: I have made an edit above.

Comment: Are you looking for how to display html content on a view from a JS var ? Like `var htmlToDisplayToView = "<div> bla bla .... </div>";` ?

Comment: sorry for a not clear question. Actually what i want is i wish to populate a div with an item which i should be able to use it in other page with same state. I did the state and controller part my self. But iam not sure which directive should be used to populate a div. Like if you see this http://gridgum.com/templates/wrapkit/ there are many widgets and i wish to have one same widget in other page with same state.

Comment: see you are asking a question about angular but you have posted static HTML.  you *seem* to be asking how to create a directive, but even that's not really obvious from what you have posted, since you aren't even showing where you would use a created directive.

Comment: your question "how do I populate a specific div" coupled with the tag angular, the answer would be "you don't".  In angular, you don't manipulate the DOM directly.  you'll need to be **a lot** more specific if you are trying to do something in angular; in particular, you need to provide the *entire* angular structure, including your `ng-app`, `ng-controller`, and controller javascript.